# Is it possible to download FIFA 14 any number of times from Origin store

Tags: origin, fifa-14

I want to purchase FIFA 14 for PC from Origin store.

I found that it shows `PC DOWNLOAD` though i purchase the game.

Is it one time download or Is it possible to download the game any number of times from the Origin store ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can re-download your game if you switch computers, need to reinstall it, et cetera. The purchase is linked to your EA Origin account, so you have access to it on any computer where you have signed into the Origin client.